# sending mails from mail box doesn't save in sent items

Tags: java, email, exchangewebservices

I am using using EWS to read a mailbox 'test@comp.com' and give in service account credentials to log into the exchange. that service account has access to read test@comp.com and even has access to send mails from it. but when I try to send out mails using following code :

```
private static void sendMailviaEWS(String to, String from, String subject,
        String body, List<String> attname, ExchangeService service) {

    try 
    {

        EmailMessage replymessage = new EmailMessage(service);
        replymessage.setSender(new EmailAddress(from));

        EmailAddress fromEmailAddress = new EmailAddress(from);
        replymessage.setFrom(fromEmailAddress);
        replymessage.getToRecipients().add(to);
        //replymessage.setInReplyTo(recipients);
        replymessage.setSubject(subject);
        replymessage.setBody(new MessageBody(body));
        replymessage.sendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);

    }catch (Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I don't see the mails getting sent from test@comp.com
the to address is mine and from address which I give in is that of test@comp.com

The sent mails always end up in sent items folder of my service account which i use to log into the exchange server.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the FolderId of the folder your saving the sent copy to so it reflects the Mailbox your sending as eg change

```
replymessage.sendAndSaveCopy(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems);
```

to

```
FolderId SentFolderForUser = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, fromEmailAddress);
replymessage.sendAndSaveCopy(SentFolderForUser);
```

Cheers
Glen

Comment: With only send-as rights and no other permissions (like full mailbox or impersonation), this doesn't seem to be working with the current EWS API as of this writing and Exchange 2013 (may apply to other versions). Have you found this to work?

Comment: It wouldn't work with send-as only because you wont have rights to save the Sent message in the SentItems folders. You might want to try the Send overload instead.