# EWS save sent item in WellKnownFolderName.SentItems

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, send, mailmessage

I'm trying to send an `EmailMessage` using `EWS` with user *A* and save the sent item in the `SentItems` folder of user *B*. Basically it works. The only problem I encounter, the item is saved as a draft and not as a sent item.

The code:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };

TimeZoneInfo timeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time");

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2, timeZone)
{
    Url = new Uri(uri),
    Credentials = new WebCredentials(new NetworkCredential(user, password, domain)),
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
};

EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(service)
{
    Subject = subject,
    Body = new MessageBody(BodyType.HTML, fullBody)
};
message.From = email;
message.ToRecipients.Add(email);

FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, email);
```

What I tried:

```
// Simply sends the message
message.Send();

// Sends the item but is it not saved in the sentItems of email-account
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, email);
message.SendAndSaveCopy(folderId);

// Sends the item, saves the item in the right folder, but it is saved as a draft, not as a sent item
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, email);
message.Send();
message.Move(folderId);
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30591340/powershell-ews-sendandsavecopy-in-specific-folder) guy tells to simply save and then save usind the folderId, but in such a scenario I get the following error:

```
This operation can't be performed because this service object already has an ID. To update this service object, use the Update() method instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

After some tests I figured out that correct procedure is the following one:

```
FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SentItems, email);
message.SendAndSaveCopy(folderId);
```

However, there must be a bug because the item is always saved in the sentItems folder of the user used to authenticate the ExchangeService ignoring the `folderId` passed as argument.
The solution (workaround) is to impersonate the user as [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/bb204095(v=exchg.140)) explains. Here the impersionation code:

```
service.AutodiscoverUrl(email);
service.ImpersonatedUserId = new ImpersonatedUserId(ConnectingIdType.SmtpAddress, email);
```

It works...I wonder if somebody else was able to arrange it in a proper way.

Comment: You can reference this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26121609/sending-mails-from-mail-box-doesnt-save-in-sent-items/26133915

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it does not work.As I mentioned in the question, the folderId where the item has to be saved is skipped if userA.Email != userB.Email. It only works using impersonation.

Comment: Maybe you could reference this link : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/cfe1a8c9-e181-49de-a1d4-accaa7e59e5d/force-a-save-into-quotsent-itemsquot-folder-for-sent-messages?forum=exchangesvrgeneral

Comment: I already tried to edit the config using `Set-MailboxSentItemsConfiguration`. Did not help.

Comment: You should save that item into a Drafts folder and then call item.Send()